# how to manipulate a url with javascript

Tags: javascript

having some trouble altering a url when the filename will change every time.

this is the url i am returning from api. the pdf name will be different evertime

> C:/Users/rsanchez/Source/completePdfs/PdfSharpResult-6-23-2015 2-13 PM.pdf

I need to change it to this

> ViewerJS/#../completePdfs/PdfSharpResult-6-23-2015 2-13 PM.pdf

what I am trying so far

```
  var fileURL = result.FileName;
                               fileURL.replace('C:/Users/rsanchez/Source/completePdfs/', 'ViewerJS/#../completePdfs/')
  $scope.returnedPdf = fileURL;
  console.log(fileURL)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it alright. Just assign the update value back to fileURL

```
fileURL = fileURL.replace('C:/Users/rsanchez/Source/completePdfs/', 'ViewerJS/#../completePdfs/')
```

Comment: Can probably skip that and go straight to $scope.returnedPdf = fileURL.replace('C:/Users/rsanchez/Source/completePdfs/', 'ViewerJS/#../completePdfs/');

Comment: @PatrickMurphy - yes this refinements can always be done. Thanks for the update.